# how to automate context menu for a window

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a simple scripting language to be used to automate the GUI of my own program. One of the macro instructions is supposed to operate on the context menu of the focused window:

CONTEXTMENU *"command name"*

So the idea is you send a `WM_CONTEXTMENU` to yourself, wait for the menu to open (class #32768), get the `HMENU` using `MN_GETHMENU`, then search the menu items for a command matching *"command name"* and finally execute that command.

The problem is that I don't want to just execute the command by its identifier number. The context menu may have complicated items sourced by an `IContextMenu` so I want somehow to convince the menu to close itself just as if the selected command was manually selected by the user. This way `TrackPopupMenu` will get the identifier number and proceed with the execution

I tried sending a `WM_COMMAND` to the menu window (#32768) but that does nothing. I am thinking to send a series of arrow keystrokes to the menu and a final VK_RETURN so that it emulates the menu command selection, but I wonder if anybody knows of a more simple/elegant way to go about this automation task?

Comment: This problem is solved already with UI Automation.

Comment: from the looks of it UI automation doesn't go [before XP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076(v=vs.85).aspx) and even there it requires .NET. I am not interested in such a solution, whatever it may be. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you want to make life hard for yourself, go for it!

Comment: UI automation is much easier to use from .NET but didn't require it. If you want to go even older than Windows XP, you can use MSAA.

Comment: thanks Raymond (I read your blog every day). It looks like AccessibleObjectFromWindow may be an option, however I didn't think of these avenues from the start, and now I'm almost finished with my code, so simulated keypresses will have to do!

Comment: If you are automating your own application, them just have an object model that people can use directly.